How do I change a key's interactions with Caps Lock using XKB?
I'm making a custom keyboard layout featuring small capital letters and I'd like to be able to use the caps lock key to type in all caps with it, but whether it's on or off, small capital letters are typed in by default. Is there a way to remedy this?

I think xbindkeys might be what you're after.

but it doesn't seem to be working is vague ... what does it do? ... please update your post

@jsotola I just edited the question, hopefully it's clearer now

it is clear now ... the caps lock key does not have any effect

Nevermind, I figured it out! In the xkb/types/caps file there are settings for the Caps Lock key!
All I had to do was add an
include "shift"

line.
